# ERROR in The target entry-point has missing dependencies: for child components

Tags: angular, angular9, angular-library

I have an angular 8 library lib-a with the child components child-x and child-y.

while consuming the lib-a in angular 9 project getting build error as below:

**ERROR in The target entry-point "@abc/lib-a" has missing dependencies:

- ./lib-a/child-x/child-x.component
- ./lib-a/child-y/child-y.component**

And the ng-package.json is,

```
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-package/ng-package.schema.json",
  "dest": "../../dist/lib-a",
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "src/public-api.ts"
  }
}
```

and the package.json of lib-a is:

```
{
  "name": "lib-a",
  "version": "1.0.6",
  "description": "lib a",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/elements": "^9.1.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3"
  }
}
```

Edit:
public-api.ts

```
export * from './lib-a/lib-a.module';
export * from './lib-a/child-x/child-x.component';
export * from './lib-a/child-y/child-y.component';
```

I tried fixing by adding the components in public-api.ts entry point, but that is not working.

I searched the web but no answers for question-related to this child component.

Comment: can you add your public-api.ts and index.ts file from you lib-a?

Comment: @ArunkumarRamasamy, I have added the public-api.ts, do you need any other additional info.

Comment: Please add index.ts file from your library.

Comment: sorry, I dont have index.ts file @ArunkumarRamasamy

Comment: are you import the ```lib-a``` module in your component module instead of component?

Comment: @Savan, did you ever figure this out?  I am having the same issue

Comment: @DJBurb, I updated the nx.json and it worked.

Comment: @Sravan nx.json?  I don't have that.  I have a ng-package.json

Comment: @DJBurb, did you figure this out? I'm having the same problem

Comment: @afriedman111 I have totally forgotten about this issue, don't even remember how I even solved this LOL

Answer (score 2):

This problem popped up for me and I was able to solve it. I have an angular library and application within my projects folder. I was playing around with using imports that refrenced the library as opposed to the absolute path of components, ie `import {mycomponent} from 'my-library'` instead of  `import {mycomponent} from 'projects/src/lib/<etc>'`. Code was lingering that pointed to the dist folder. Once I deleted the dist folder, the real errors showed (these references). Once I fixed these errors the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

One good general and easy solution is to delete node_modules and install them again using command

```
npm install
```